# Aquire a specific domain name

Tags: web, dns

I have a basic knowledge of the domain name system, however I have never bought a domain. I wish to acquire a very specific domain name for the sake of fleshing out my understanding.

Instead of acquiring a domain such as: 'websitename.com'

I would like something like: 'web.site.name'

I have browsed domain name providers and there seems to be some that break the '.com' mould such as '.horse' and '.cool'. But is there a way of getting a very specific domain name of your choosing or do you have to compromise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are thousands, upon thousands! of domain registrars who are all quite eager to take your money, and help you choose the domain you're looking for.

As for `web.site.com` for that you would need to purchase, `site.com` Once you have that you can add anything you want in front of it.

If the very specific name you want is already taken, then you can't have it. If it is available you can.

New Top level domains such as .horse .cool were introduced because the .com namespace is very overcrowded, you're unlikely to find anything specific there, as it will probably be taken already.

Search for domain name registrars, put some names in their search boxes, if they say they're available you can hand over your credit card details and have it.